# Would almond flour work for macarons?

Tags: dessert, almonds, macarons

I've been trying to make macarons using almond meal, and they turn out very lumpy and grainy. Should I be using almond flour instead? Or doing something else to make the powder finer?

Comment: Found this while trying to answer the same question: http://www.differencebetween.net/object/comparisons-of-food-items/difference-between-almond-flour-and-ground-almonds/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here I'm assuming that you mean macaroons as in the French patisserie *[macarons](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Macaron)* rather than the simpler coconut or almond based *[macaroons](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Macaroon)*.

In any case almond meal and almond flour are essentially the same thing, both are almonds ground into a fine (or not so much in your case) 'flour' or 'powder'. [Apparently](http://lowcarbdiets.about.com/od/products/p/almondmeal.htm), almond flour is made from 'blanched' (almonds which have had their skin removed) almonds whereas almond meal can be made from either almonds with their skins on (whole) or 'blanched'. I have, however, always found them to be used interchangeably.

If your problem is graininess, then you could either sieve the ground almonds before using or blitz/grind them finer in a food processor until the desired consistency is reached, however if you're grinding them in a food processor make sure you do it in small batches or if you're making macarons blitz them with the icing sugar (for the *tant pour tant*) to avoid making [almond butter](http://www.wisegeek.com/what-is-almond-butter.htm). Personally, I would do both to achieve a fine powder.

Comment: You can avoid making almond butter by blitzing the almonds with the powdered sugar.

Answer (score 3):

Almond flour and almond meal are pretty much interchangeable terms. What you are essentially looking for is the finest ground almonds you can get hold of.

I buy ground almonds (because they're easily obtained) and sift them to get the finest bits. This isn't very economical (90g of fine almonds from a 150g bag, usually) but you can use the coarser bits in other baking.

Answer (score 1):

According to this article on how.com (regarding low-carb diets), if you use only blanched almonds, instead of ones with skins, you'll get a finer flour:

http://lowcarbdiets.about.com/od/products/p/almondmeal.htm